# Mod Rewrite in Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having issues with mod_rewrite when trying to route all calls to one directory to one single script in that directory. This simple rule was working on linux:

RewriteRule * api.cgi

In the error log on this OS, for this I get "RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '*'".

I've tried a few other things, and mod rewrite is working on some matches, but only on filenames and not the directory paths.

Eg. RewriteRule .* api.cgi - routes anything with a filename to api.cgi which proves it is working, but I want to route /api/config/ to api.cgi. I can only seem to get /api/config/something.something to actually force the rewrite - ie it needs a filename.

Any ideas? I literally want to route absolutely everything called in this directory to api.cgi, no matter how many directories deep or whether or not it has a filename at the end of it.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^ api.cgi
```

But normally the result is exactly the same with

```
RewriteRule .* api.cgi
```

If you have done many tests, it is possible that it is a cache problem. Try to clear your cache or with another browser.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issues.

Both RewriteRule ^ api.cgi and RewriteRule .* api.cgi will redirect anything with a . in it, but not if it is only a file path. So /api/config.html will redirect, /api/config. will redirect, but /api/config will not. The error message given is a standard 404

The requested URL /~username/cgi-bin/api2/config was not found on this server.

Obviously the url isn't there but it is supposed to redirect instead of 404.

Comment: No, in the Regular expression `.*`: The asterisk indicates zero or more occurrences of the preceding element. And `.` Matches any single character. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: I think the problem is in your cgi